# Jquery length property always returning 0

Tags: jquery, html

I have some form elements added via ajax in to a table as below.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input id="cde[0]" name="cde[0]" class="required" value="30-09-2015">
        <input type="hidden" id="cddbe[0]" name="cddbe[0]" value="2015-09-30">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="cqtye[0]" name="cqtye[0]" class="required number" value="30">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="cremarke[0]" name="cremarke[0]" value="remarks 1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

There may be many rows of elements like this in the table.

I am trying to find if an element exists before getting its value using jquery.length property as below

```
var nor=$('#commite tr').size()-2;
var c="cqtye["+nor+"]";
if($('#'+c).length){
  console.log("element exists");
}
```

But .length is always false. When I check length for elements outside the table it is returning 1. But on elements inside this table it is always 0.

This table is inside a div and bith div and table have unique Ids.

Can some one guide me how to check if an element exists in this case.

Comment: what is the value of `c`

Comment: did you check for the `nor` value? try `console.log(nor);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `[]` i.e. meta-characters in ID, these needs to be escaped.

*Use*

```
var c="cqtye\\["+nor+"\\]";
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

```js
$(function() {
  var nor = $('#commite tr').length;
  var c="cqtye\\["+nor+"\\]";
  if ($('#' + c).length) {
    snippet.log("element exists");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input id="cde[0]" name="cde[0]" class="required" value="30-09-2015">
      <input type="hidden" id="cddbe[0]" name="cddbe[0]" value="2015-09-30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="cqtye[0]" name="cqtye[0]" class="required number" value="30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="cremarke[0]" name="cremarke[0]" value="remarks 1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: interesting answers, who will win :) different statements pointed out

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi, as OP is using ID selector, escaping meta-character will give performance benefit  over attribute value selector

Comment: No change. I tried to use firebug's console to get length using $('#cqtye[0]').length but still it returns 0

Comment: @sknagesh read my answer carefully you need to use  `$('#cqtye\\[0\\]').length`

Comment: @Satpal can i ask something about the `nor` it is not in the html but you come up with it anyway what attr is that

Comment: @Pekka, You can read OP's code `var nor=$('#commite tr').size()-2;`

Comment: i get it now i got confused because i keep comparing both that answers and i got lost in the nor part.thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the css meta character while creating jquery selector or use name value selector instead:

```
if($("[id='"+c+"']").length){
   console.log("element exists");
}
```

Comment: interesting answers, who will win :) different statements pointed out